# going from font-awesome v4 to v5

Tags: html, css, class, font-awesome, responsive

I've been using [some responsive template](https://www.html5webtemplates.co.uk/templates/elements/) for a while now but would like to upgrade its fa-module from v4 to v5. after downloading [the free web package](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself) and swapping "font-awesome.min.css" with "all.min.css" and adapting all references to the new font folder, I can use all new fa-icons with `"<span class="fa fa-..."></span>"` (or far, fas, fab prefixed). good.
What I can't get to work properly is using v5 icons with additional styles, eg `class="icon ..."` or `class="feature ..."`.
only the v5 solid family gets displayed when I explicitly set
`.icon:before { ... font-weight: 900; ... }` or `.feature:before { ... font-weight: 900; ... }`. icons from the other 2 families get displayed as a square box showing the icon's hex code only.
when I set a weight of "400", only icons from the v5 regular family are displayed and the solid ones show up as squares with hex codes. whatever weight I set, the v5 brands family icons never show up.
So how can I access the icons from the brands family or from all 3 families alike?
Thanks for any hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to tell the browser which Font Awesome family you want to use. Just like if you wanted `Arial` vs `Times` to display text on your site.

In your code block you should say:

```
.icon:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
}
```

In the case of Font Awesome, it's a combination of `font-family` and `font-weight` that produce the different looks.

---

The real issue is that you're using the *free* version of FA which only includes the "solid" and "Brands" styles by specifying the 900 weight and the 400 weight. The features you're requesting are part of the Pro version.

[image]

Here's [FA's Documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) on this issue.

Comment: Thanks Bryce. Actually the free version includes all 3 styles but thanks to your hint, I re-read thru my CSS code and noticed the "brands" style's font-family name is "Font Awesome 5 Brands". So along with a weight of 400 all fa-brands icons are available. With "Font Awesome 5 Free" and a weight of 400 all fa-regular and a weight of 900 all fa-solid icons. Great.

Comment: Glad it worked! I kind of wish each style was simply a different font package that would make it easier. Though I'm surprised their docs are that far off.